# how to repeat the process in shell script

Tags: shell, sh

Hi i am new to shell script.in my shell script i want to repeat the process.

```
script.sh
echo "Enter the city name"
read cityname
echo "Enter the state name"
read statename
pig -x mapreduce mb_property_table_updated.pig city=$cityname state=$statename
echo "Do you want to run for another city"
```

if yes means i want to repeat the processs again else it will move to next process.any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use while loop

```
line=yes
while [ "$line" = yes ]
do
echo "Enter the city name"
read cityname
echo "Enter the state name"
read statename
pig -x mapreduce mb_property_table_updated.pig city=$cityname state=$statename
echo "Do you want to run for another city"
read line
done
```

And also in for loop

```
for((;;))
do
echo "Enter the city name"
read cityname
echo "Enter the state name"
read statename
pig -x mapreduce mb_property_table_updated.pig city=$cityname state=$statename
echo "Do you want to run for another city"
read answer
if [ "$answer" = "yes" ]
then
continue
else
break
fi
done
```

Comment: `for((;;))` is a `bash`ism, and may not be available in your shell.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this:

```
while [ "$e" != "n" ]; do
    echo "Enter the city name"
    read cityname
    echo "Enter the state name"
    read statename
    pig -x mapreduce mb_property_table_updated.pig city=$cityname state=$statename
    echo "Do you want to run for another city (y/n)"
    read e
done
```

Answer (score 0):

For completeness, there is also an often overlooked `until` loop in shell.

```
until [ "$answer" = no ]; do
    echo "Enter the city name"
    read cityname
    echo "Enter the state name"
    read statename
    pig -x mapreduce mb_property_table_updated.pig city=$cityname state=$statename
    echo "Do you want to run for another city"
    read answer
done
```